May I ask advice on better topology?
Introduction
I'm still considered a beginner when it comes to topology! Anyways, I boolean'ed a cube to create a power outlet model. Of course, booleans can mess up topology a lot so I had to fix normals, floating vertices, faces with an edge crossing over it, etc. The two square inlets, don't have any support edge loops.
Problem
I would like some suggestions especially for the topology that connects the the half-circle. I was wondering if I should reduce edges to 3 to 1 for example. The screenshot doesn't have ngons, but was it better if I used some to terminate some edge loops or something? Thanks in advance!


hello the topology is a bit messy but depending on your project you may not need to have a good one and you could even do a X > Limited Dissolve, unless you have a good reason to have a good topology?

Hi thanks for looking at this post! Well for this mesh, it will be sitting on the corner of a table, somewhat far from the camera so I guess it doesn't need a good topology.

Bad topology doesn't matter in itself as moonboots pointed out. If you don't use tool that depends on topology (bevel, subdiv, ...), no need to clean that up. Do you have any issue with your topology ? Besides esthetic considerations.

It's not that it doesn't require a good topology, it's that what constitutes a good topology is different in context. The goal of topology is to make the object look good, deform good, and/or easy to work with. If it's a static model, no need for deformation-specific topology. If it's a final mesh, no need to keep a workable topology. But while the looking-good always remain, it also has its own sub-constraints: do you use a subdiv modifier or not? It has its own topology needs. Is your front face purely flat? It has its own needs too. Etc.

And there's also the simple question of how much time it costs to make it better vs how worth the benefit is. If your mesh is going to be in the corner of your final render, in shade, and barely more than a few pixels, .... No need to fiddle too much. So long it looks good "enough" for what it needs to do.

Very cool, thank you for the comments! To clarify, if this power outlet model "looks good" in the end despite its wonky topology in the final render, then it has achieved its goals? Just a thought, if this mesh were to exist in a mobile video game, then would these kinds of topology be of concern because of non-optimized tris and ngon data?

Suggestion, do as in this image.
Use knife and dissolves.


Thank you for the suggestion everyone, I was able to simplify the mesh more. However, it seems like it's another story when I have to think about more edge loops and ngons on the back side of the power outlet.
[

The backside that is in the wall and therefore invisible? You don't even need a back side, right?

Hmm that is a good point. Is it suggested not have a back side to prevent two faces from overlapping?

No, it's just useless to make things you won't see.

I see, thank you for the clarification!
